# Intermittent Cassandra read failure, possibly from timeout

Tags: cassandra

I'm running into an intermittent problems reading from Cassandra.  The problems occurs using both cqlsh and the java driver.

For example, in cqlsh, the command

> select distinct count(partitionKeyColumnName) from a_table;

usually works as expected, but occasionally throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/moi/h/sw_projects/senta12/apache-cassandra-3.5/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1317, in perform_simple_statement
result = future.result()
File "/home/user/apache_dir/apache-cassandra-3.5/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.0.0-6af642d.zip/cassandra-driver-3.0.0-6af642d/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3122, in result raise self._final_exception
ReadFailure: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

If I issue the same command using the java driver, again the results are usually correct, but occasionally the driver throws

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:85)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:27)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:63)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:39)
...
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:76)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:37)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:266)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:246)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
```

Configuration (this is essentially a test system):

- A completely vanilla installation of apache-cassandra-3.5 running on a single node.
- No parameters have been changed.
- cassandra-java-driver-3.0.0.
- The keyspace has a replication factor=1.
- The clients (cqlsh and java driver) are on the same physical system as the Cassandra server (i.e. all access is local)
- There is only *one* client accessing Cassandra at a time.

The table being queried has ~122 million rows distributed (fairly evenly) over 730 partition key values.

The inconsistency of the problem is troubling and I'm not at all sure how to interpret it.  Perhaps something in the server is timing out, but if that were the case I'd expect more consistent failures, especially since the load on the system is always the same.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I would take a look at garbage collection. It's possible that timeouts occur when GC is taking place. This would account for it being an intermittent problem. Look for GCInspector.java events in the system.log and see if they happen at the same time as your timeouts.

Comment: It appears that the problem only occurs when Cassandra is first launched.  After it's been up for a 'short time' - perhaps five minutes - the error no longer occurs.  Why this should be the case is not at all clear.  With smaller tables, it never occurs.

Comment: perhaps cassandra is still replaying the commitlogs? I find it often takes 2-3 minutes for cassandra to fully initialize.

Comment: That sounds likely.  Is there any way to determine when initialization is complete? Thanks.

Comment: Look for this entry in the system.log file `INFO  [main] 2016-07-07 13:10:16,537  Server.java:182 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042...` (probably will see your local IP address)

Comment: Slow queries at launch could also be a consequence of JIT: method calls on the JVM typically don't get any optimization until they've been called 10,000 times, and the optimization generally gets better the more they're called.